# How to delete a info with ID from JSON based data

Tags: json, node.js

The content of my JSON file is:
This is my retails.json file.actually retails is my database.i converted this json file from sql database.so in this json file, I want to delete a person information with a single ID.How can i do? i am using node.js and express.

```
{
"categories" : [
{
"dept_id" : "123",
"category_name" : "database",
"category_discription" : "list of database",
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:27:17",
"id" : "1"
},
{
"dept_id" : "1234",
"category_name" : "debugging",
"category_discription" : "program debugger",
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:32:24",
"id": "2"
},
{
"dept_id" : "12345",
"category_name" : "system analyzer",
"category_discription" : null,
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:33:23",
"id" : "3"
}
],
"departments" : [
{
"name" : "manpreet singh",
"address_info" : "qadian",
"current time" : null,
"id" : "1"
},
{
"name" : "tushal gupta",
"address_info" : "amritsar",
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:10:14",
"id" : "2"
},
{
"name" : "haroop singh",
"address_info" : "amritsar",
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:11:12",
"id" : "3"
}
],

"digital_marketing" : [
{
"dept_id" : "123",
"phone" : "99889988",
"mobile" : null,
"email" : "thbs@gmail.com",
"web" : null,
"facebook" : null,
"twitter" : null,
"linkedin" : null,
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:10:16",
"id" : "1"
},
{
"dept_id" : "1234",
"phone" : "998899888",
"mobile" : null,
"email" : null,
"web" : null,
"facebook" : "gtudgal@fb.com",
"twitter" : "tushalgupta",
"linkedin" : null,
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:30:19",
"id" : "2"
},
{
"dept_id" : "12345",
"phone" : "99889877",
"mobile" : null,
"email" : "fhdts@mail.com",
"web" : null,
"facebook":"sdfh33@fb.com",
"twitter" : null,
"linkedin" : null,
"current time" : "2016-07-21 06:30:13",
"id" : "3"  
} 
]
}
```

I am using this to delete a ID, but does not work:

```
var id = 2;
app.get('/deleteUser', function (req, res) {   
// First read existing users.  
fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "retails.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {       
data = JSON.parse( data );      
 delete data["categories" + 2];       
     console.log( data );
     res.end( JSON.stringify(data));
   });
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. You pasted the content of a JSON file that does not contain anything on `users`  -so what are you deleting? What is the content of the `users.json`?

Comment: sorry for that. i edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var prop in jsonObj.categories){
   delete jsonObj.categories[prop].id;
}
```

similar for digital_marketing etc. jsonObj is the data in your case..

Comment: where to write this?? after what?

Comment: your answer only delete a ID.but i want to delete a information with a single ID.

Comment: then us it like for (...) { if( jsonObj.categories[prop].id == YOURDELETEID ) delete jsonObj.categories[prop]; }

Comment: thanku.its working......and how about if i want to delete more than one id..like localhost.../categories/1 or localhost:../categories/2 or localhost:../categories/3

Comment: var ids2delete= [ 1, 2, 3, 4] ; and the if ( ids2delete.indexOf(jsonObj.categories[prop].id) > -1) { delete jsonObj.categories[prop]}

Comment: or you can write { if( jsonObj.categories[prop].id == req.params.id ) delete jsonObj.categories[prop]; }

Comment: i want to show this json data on web browser using angularjs..how can i do it??